# Did Goku trigger the creation of Goku Black

Tags: dragon-ball-super

According to Dragon Ball super episode 53, Goku, Beerus and Whis visit Universe 10, where goku has a fight with Kaioshin Zamasu. After their fight zamasu hatred towards humans increase much more and also he comes to know about Time rings, which he had no idea. His hatred towards humans, especially Goku caused for the creation of Goku Black

So therefore trunks coming to past, made goku meet zamasu indirectly trigerring the creation of Goku Black. Therefore creating a time loop

Is my suspicion correct?

Comment: yes you are completely correct in what you are suspecting if you want more information you can watch this video I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlGM_srKkgk

Answer (score 3):

This is true. Though IMHO, this was not necessary for Zamasu to hate Goku and the other humans.

In dragon ball super episode 57, Zamasu sees Goku fight in the universe 6 tournament and realizes that Goku, though a mortal, can reach the level of Gods. This enrages him and is the immediate trigger for him to find Zuno to get knowledge about Goku and the Super dragon balls. This subsequently led to the creation of Goku Black.

So Trunks coming to past and Goku meeting Zamasu was just a effect of the time travel but did not lead to the cause. Thus there is no time loop. This is more evident in the manga, where Goku does not meet Zamasu in the present. Instead Zamasu just hears about Goku defeating Majin Buu from Shin.